# FactoryPattern to construct objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

The question is about `GoF` interpretation of the Factory pattern.

I have a `Tree<SqlRestriction>` where

```
public interface SqlRestriction{
     public String getSql();
}
```

Now, I need to create an object of the interface called Container:

```
public interface Container{
    //methods
}
```

Here is one of its implementation:

```
public class SimpleSqlListContainer implements Container{
    private Integer rate;
    private String relation;
    //GET, SET, CTORs, other methods
}
```

So, I tend to wrap the objects creation into a factory

```
public class ContainerFactory{
    public Container create(Tree<SqlRestriction> restrinctions){
         //impl
    }
}
```

The actual creation as well as ***proper initialization*** are going to be performed by traversing the `Tree` passed as a parameter.

***QUESTION:*** If I initialize the object that is being created within the factory method, would it be considered good. Or it can mislead other developers? So, in factory method, should we avoid any kind of initialization and just perform the object creation, leaving the initialization to the client.

Comment: It's unclear what the difference is between construction and initialization. Both should generally be done by the constructor. A constructed object should be ready to use, in general. What matters the most if the documentation: make it clear what the factory does and return.

Comment: @JBNizet But in JavaBean we generally have deafult constructor that usually has empty body and getters/setters?

Comment: Not everything should be a JavaBean. And even if a JavaBean has a no-arg constructor, it should be (and is, generally) usable without having to call any setter.

Comment: This comment is irrelevant , but If I remember correctly, in the GoF pattern the factory also implemented `IContainerFactory`

Answer (score 2):

The GoF pattern says nothing about object initialization (I've reread the chapter just to make sure). The only purpose of the pattern is to hide the type selection inside the factory implementation.

That said, if you build a number of objects of a certain type, and every of them has the same initialization sequence, for instance:

```
public IFoo createFoo(){
    ConcreteFoo foo = new ConcreteFoo();
    foo.setField1("a");
    foo.setField2("b");
    ....
    foo.setFieldN("z");
    return foo;
}
```

Any initialization sequence that is repeated multiple times in the code should be encapsulated somewhere to avoid code repetition. This initialization could go in the constructor only if it applied to every possible instance of that class. I'm talking about default values. Now if the initialization sequence does not apply to every instance of a class, and instead it is taylor-made for a certain purpose, it should be taken out of the constructor.

The factory implementation would then be a good candidate for this, as long as the initialization use case is common enough in your application. The Factory interface would look like this:

```
public interface IFooFactory {
    public IFoo createFooForThis();
    public IFoo createFooForThat();

    ...

}
```

In fact, if we need to call setters on the foo instance that belong to the `ConcreteFoo` class and are not present in the `IFoo` interface, this is the only place where you can do this, because the client code cannot call methods other than the ones in the `IFoo` interface.

Answer (score 1):

The factory patterns concern is to make a decision based on the supplied parameters what type of object to return. It encapsulates that logic. If there are other implementations of the Container class that would be suitable for the particular type of SqlRestriction then the factory would make that decision for you.

The concern of initializing the Container, seems to me to belong to the Container itself. As it would know how it needs to traverse the Tree it is passed in order to contain the objects.